# Populating Dropdown in ember js

Tags: ember.js

My template is like

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >

    {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="ResAdmin.adminController.softwares" selectionBinding="ResAdmin.adminController.selection" optionLabelPath="name" optionValuePath="id" }}   

</script>
```

And my controller is like

```
ResAdmin.adminController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    selection: {
        id: '889C0E73-1587-41D5-8073-FD29FF76CF00',
        name: "$$"},
    softwares: [
        {
        id: '92E9862E-DAE5-4CC8-ACDF-7E6418641F7D',
        name: "$"},
    {
        id: '889C0E73-1587-41D5-8073-FD29FF76CF00',
        name: "$$"},
    {
        id: '47A56B26-A64A-4967-A9F6-B9D69B2CA145',
        name: "$$$"},
    {
        id: '417993DB-48BF-4BA9-BE0A-D6A53C6D8325',
        name: "$$$$"}
    ]
});
```

My dropdown is not generating. If i remove the selectionBinding from the template my dropdown seems to be generating but in my dropdown the label is not displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way of doing this would be to define your data on the controller backing up your template. It seams your template is the default `application` so therefore, try changing the path of `optionValuePath` and  `optionLabelPath` including `content` as the prefix, and also using directly the templates controller context like:

### ApplicationController

```
ResAdmin.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  selection: {
    id: '889C0E73-1587-41D5-8073-FD29FF76CF00',
    name: "$$"
  },
  softwares: [
    {
      id: '92E9862E-DAE5-4CC8-ACDF-7E6418641F7D',
      name: "$"
    },
    {
      id: '889C0E73-1587-41D5-8073-FD29FF76CF00',
      name: "$$"
    },
    {
      id: '47A56B26-A64A-4967-A9F6-B9D69B2CA145',
      name: "$$$"
    },
    {
      id: '417993DB-48BF-4BA9-BE0A-D6A53C6D8325',
      name: "$$$$"
    }
  ]
});
```

### application template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
  {{view Ember.Select 
    contentBinding="controller.softwares"
    selectionBinding="controller.selection" 
    optionLabelPath="content.name" 
    optionValuePath="content.id"
    prompt="Select..."}}
</script>
```

Working [example](http://jsbin.com/iFoZIza/4/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is working now, i used valueBinding instead of selectionBinding.